# UICollectionView. How Present viewController with a different element (not only first) without animation?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I need present UICollectionView, with a different element (not only first) without animation.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3JoX.gif)

my code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
   super.viewWillAppear(animated) 

   DispatchQueue.main.async { 
       var newPoint = self.productCollectionView.contentOffset 
       newPoint.x = (UIScreen.main.bounds.width * CGFloat(self.currentPage)) + 1 
       self.productCollectionView.contentOffset = newPoint 
  } 

}
```

Comment: This question needs more detail. Is the problem that only one element is being shown? Is the problem that you're getting an animation you don't want? What have you tried? It's generally a bad sign if your entire post is your title.

Comment: @Dopapp I using method scrollToItem with animation: false in method viewWillAppear. But my collection doesn't scroll to an element. If I using DispatchQueue.main.async my collection scrolling but I see the first element before my element with a blink.

Comment: So you want to start at a certain contentOffset when the ViewController is presented?

Comment: @Dopapp Yes. Sorry, but I know English is not very good.

Comment: @Dopapp contentOffset doesn't work for me.

Comment: Could you show the code you’ve tried?

Comment: @Dopapp Yes, sure. 

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
DispatchQueue.main.async {
            var newPoint = self.productCollectionView.contentOffset
            newPoint.x = (UIScreen.main.bounds.width * CGFloat(self.currentPage)) + 1
            self.productCollectionView.contentOffset = newPoint
        }
}

Comment: Please put it in your question and format it correctly

Comment: @Dopapp I made it. Can you check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting `contentOffset`, call the `setContentOffset(_:, animated:)` method with an `animated:` value of `false`.

Also I would suggest removing the `async` and moving your code to `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. That way, your code will run before the user sees anything, but after the initial layout of the view has been achieved. This method can be called many times, so you will have to use a Bool instance property to make sure it only runs once.

Comment: Could you please tell me? After change this property UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft, setContentOffset or scrollToItem doesn't work, but if change to .forceLeftToRight it works.